# How to tell Eclipse to show content assist automatically?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

When I am typing Eclipse does not automatically shows content assist, but only after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.
I used to type class name and Eclipse gave good proposals automatically.
But now it is not working.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Go to, Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Auto activation triggers for Java, and enter `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` , this will trigger the auto activation for class names, methods, etc.

Comment: I also inserted the @ sign, which is useful for annotation autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

Look in Preferences in Java / Editor / Content Assist and check the `Enable auto activation` check box is ticked and has a sensible delay.

Comment: Thanks! It is checked and delay is 200ms. Auto-activation triggers is set to dot(.) meaning content-assist is only when dot is typed. But I used to type class name or method name and eclipse poped-up content- assist right away.