# Eclipse- autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I recently downloaded and installed Eclipse Standard/ SDK, version: Kepler Service Release 2.

In the past, when using Eclipse, there has been an 'autocomplete' function available when typing, that would try to 'guess' what keywords and variable names you were typing- if it guessed the correct one, you just had to press 'tab' to get it to fill in automatically for you.

However, this autocomplete function doesn't seem to work with the current version of Eclipse that I'm using... and I can't seem to find a way to turn it on- I've tried Edit -> Word Completion, and Edit -> Content Assist, but neither of these options seem to make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry- did have a look for an answer to this, but didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to, Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Auto activation triggers for java, and enter `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` , this will trigger the auto activation for class names, methods, etc...

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456027/1546513).