# How to make Eclipse not insert Content Assist suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion, content-assist

In order to make Eclipse's content assist more like Intellij's, I changed the "auto activation triggers" setting to pop up the content assist window whenever I type, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449175).

However, now whenever I press <kbd>Space</kbd> it inserts the content assist suggestion, even though I wanted to type a space.

Is there a way to make eclipse insert the suggestion *only* when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not when I press space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control this. Open a feature request in Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org .

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences>>Java>>Editor>>Content Assist, select ***Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'***. This handles the space bar issue.

You'll still get inserts sometimes, when there is only one proposal. I lived with this for a while, but I needed to disable it so I could use content assist in a plug-in to only provide suggestions.

You can turn this off by disabling ***Insert Single Proposals Automatically*** in the same menu.

Answer (score 0):

Below image shows how can you bind the key to Content Assist command.

[image: Mapping the Keys]

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. I want to change the key that actually *inserts* the suggestion, not the key to trigger content assist